# No overload for 'Update' matches delegate 'Action<UnityModManager.ModEntry,float>'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm updating a mod for Planetbase but the entry method gives me issues.
The error is:

```
No overload for 'Update' matches delegate 'Action<UnityModManager.ModEntry,float>'
```

Here is the snipped of the source code that I have problem with, error at line 13:

```
    using Planetbase;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using UnityModManagerNet;

namespace Tahvohck_Mods
{
    public class BetterHours_Main 
    {
        [LoaderOptimization(LoaderOptimization.NotSpecified)]
        public static void Init(UnityModManager.ModEntry modData)
        {
            modData.OnUpdate = Update;
        }
#pragma warning disable IDE0060 // Remove unused parameter
        public void Update(UnityModManager.ModEntry modData, PlanetDefinition planetDefinition)
#pragma warning restore IDE0060 // Remove unused parameter
        {
            StatsCollector sCollector = Singleton<StatsCollector>.getInstance();
            EnvironmentManager eManager = Singleton<EnvironmentManager>.getInstance();
            _ = (Singleton<EnvironmentManager>.getInstance().getDayTime() + Singleton<EnvironmentManager>.getInstance().getNightTime()) / 6f;

            if (sCollector != null && eManager != null)
            {
                float dayHours = (float)GetDayHours(planetDefinition);
                _ = (float)((eManager.getDayTime() + (double)eManager.getNightTime()) / (dayHours / 6.0));
            }
        }
```

Help would be welcome as I just started working with Planetbase mods.

Comment: The problem is in this statement: `modData.OnUpdate = Update;`. As the error message says, the `OnUpdate` event is expecting a method that receives a `ModEntry` as the first parameter and a `float` as the second parameter. Your `Update` method takes `PlanetDefinition` as the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks. The error is gone.

Comment: @JackA. please post your comment as an answer so that OP can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this statement:

```
modData.OnUpdate = Update;
```

The reason is that your `Update` method doesn't match the type that is expected by the `OnUpdate` event. If you look at the error message, it will tell you what is wrong:

> No overload for 'Update' matches delegate **'Action<UnityModManager.ModEntry,float>'**

The bolded part tells you the type that is required for the `OnUpdate` event. `Action` is a generic delegate type, and the types in the angle brackets tell you the required parameter types.

You can see here that it is expecting a method that receives a `ModEntry` as the first parameter and a `float` as the second parameter. Your `Update` method takes `PlanetDefinition` as the second parameter, so it doesn't match.